# master page link button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a link button in the master page "HOME".When I click this link I have to move to Service providers home page(to particular provider page) if I have logged in as service provider, else should log in as service seeker home page.

Comment: And where are you having difficulties?

Comment: I were able to scroll to only one of those pages by setting Response.redirect(serviceprovider.aspx or serviceseeker.aspx)how can i make them to scroll to the different pages based on the login privilege?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what problem your are facing. Is it not easy to use if else?
on click of "Home" button below code can be written:

```
void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(//user has 1 permission)
    {
      //goto page1.aspx use response.redirect here
    }
    else if(//user has 2 permission)
    {
      //goto page2.aspx use response.redirect here
    }
    ....and so on.
}
```